# ¿Cómo Utilizar fillable Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo duda de que campos debo poner en **fillable** , Tengo entendido que Se produce una vulnerabilidad de asignación masiva cuando un usuario pasa un parámetro HTTP inesperado a través de una solicitud, y ese parámetro cambia una columna en su base de datos que no esperaba por lo cual ahí que poner el **fillable** cuales son los campos que vamos a permitir que se asignen en masa ,
mi pregunta es que nombre debo poner en **fillable** ,  los que les di a mis input o los nombres de mis campos en la base de datos.

por ejemeplo : yo tengo un `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombre_Pelicula">`, pero en la base de datos se llama **nombre_pelicula** , entonces el el fillable deberia poner

> protected $fillable = ['Nombre_Pelicula'] o protected $fillable =
> ['nombre_pelicula']

**Funcion Update**

public function update(Request $request,Pelicula $pelicula)
{

```
        $pelicula->fill($request->except('imagen_pelicula'));
        
        if ($request->hasFile('Imagen_Pelicula')) {
            $archivo = $request->file('Imagen_Pelicula');
            $Nombre_Imagen = time().$archivo->getClientOriginalName();
            $pelicula->imagen_pelicula = $Nombre_Imagen;
            $archivo->move(public_path().'/img/peliculas' , $Nombre_Imagen );   
        }  
       
        $pelicula->save();
        return redirect('peliculas');
    }
```

**Formulario**

```
 <br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('peliculas.index') }}"> Ver Peliculas  </a>
    <form style="width: 800px;border:0px red solid;margin:auto"  method="post" action="{{ asset('/peliculas') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="form-row">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-6">
           <label for="Nombre_Pelicula">Nombre Pelicula</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nombre_Pelicula" id="Nombre_Pelicula" placeholder="Nombre Pelicula" >
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label for="Director_Pelicula">Director</label>
           <input type="Director_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Director_Pelicula" id="Director_Pelicula" placeholder="Director_Pelicula">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label for="Genero_Pelicula">Genero</label>
           <input type="Genero_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Genero_Pelicula" id="Genero_Pelicula" placeholder="Genero_Pelicula">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="Idioma_Pelicula">Idioma</label>
            <input type="Idioma_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Idioma_Pelicula" id="Idioma_Pelicula" placeholder="Idioma_Pelicula">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6" >
            <div style="padding:0px" class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Duracion_Pelicula">Duracion</label>
                <input type="Duracion_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Duracion_Pelicula" id="Duracion_Pelicula" placeholder="Duracion_Pelicula">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0px" class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Año_Pelicula">Año</label>
                <input type="Año_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Año_Pelicula" id="Año_Pelicula" placeholder="Año_Pelicula">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0px" class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Calidad_Pelicula">Calidad</label>
                <input type="Calidad_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Calidad_Pelicula" id="Calidad_Pelicula" placeholder="Calidad_Pelicula">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0px" class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Precio_Pelicula">Precio</label>
                <input type="Precio_Pelicula" class="form-control" name="Precio_Pelicula" id="Precio_Pelicula" placeholder="Precio Pelicula">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0px" class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="Imagen_Pelicula">Imagen Pelicula</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="Imagen_Pelicula" id="Imagen_Pelicula" >
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-6" >
          <label for="Descripcion_Pelicula">Descripcion</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" name="Descripcion_Pelicula" id="Descripcion_Pelicula"  > </textarea>
        </div>
        
       </div>
       {{csrf_field()}}
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
     </form>
     <br>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial, debes poner el nombre del atributo (el cual no necesariamente el nombre del campo en la base de datos), o en este caso, y en su forma más simple, el nombre del campo en la base de datos.

```
protected $fillable = ['nombre_pelicula'];
```

¿Qué atributos no deberías incluir en dicho array?

Aquellos que consideres sensibles y que no deberían modificarse o asignarse en cierta forma, el más típico es el **id**, el cual normalmente no se modifica ni se asigna de forma manual.

Por último, revisa también las propiedades `$guarded` y `$hidden`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Tambien Pense que debiria de poner  **protected $fillable = ['nombre_pelicula'];** pero no punciona en cambio si pongo **protected $fillable = ['Nombre_Pelicula']** si funciona , en este caso me esta toamado el nombre del campo input y no el de la base de datos.

Comment: Nunca he hecho esa incoherencia de ponerle un nombre con un case distinto al campo en la base de datos y otro al input, o si lo hago, es con nombres totalmente distintos, pero manteniendo el estilo de case. En todo caso es posible que sea case-insensitive o que estés modificando algo más. Tendría que revisar con más detalle el código.

Comment: explicame porque le llamas incoherencia en que estoy fallando?

Comment: No es lo mismo "nombre_pelicula" que "Nombre_Pelicula". Cada quien es libre de escoger la convención de case que desee para los nombres a lo largo del proyecto, pero sea cual sea la convención, debería mantenerse idealmente en todo el proyecto, con ciertas excepciones.

Comment: me quieres decir que lo mejor seria usar los mismo nombres de la base de datos paro los nombre de mi proyecto , es decir , si en la base de datos se llama **nombre_pelicula** en input también debería llamarse **nombre_pelicula** ..  asi **<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_pelicula">**

Comment: No necesariamente es lo mejor, pero sí lo más fácil para evitar problemas potenciales por cambio de convenciones.

Comment: listo , los cambie para usar siempre el mismo nombre y  así evitar problemas como tu me dices , ya se que siempre uso el mismo nombre y escrito de la misma manera , gracias por tu ayuda.